# Wrapping 3D noise functions like simplex and perlin in c#

Tags: c#, procedural-generation, terrain, perlin-noise, simplex-noise

I'm experimenting with loop-able worlds that have a height-map for terrain data. 
While I can easily create loop-able .BMP textures for this in Photoshop and just load the terrain from them, but that limits the size and variance of the worlds to whatever I pre-generate for the player.

I would like to proceduralize the process. I have got a simplex terrain and a perlin terrain generator and I'd like to wrap them so that the world loops back around to the same place if you travel in a straight line in any direction North East South West

What would be the best techniques to use to wrap the noise to a tillable terrain.

This question Different as it is for both perlin AND simplex.
It is also different as I forgot to mention I am using 3D noise for some of my work.

Comment: I will try and work from the other thread but my queery still stands

Comment: What query do you have remaining that isn't answered by the duplicate?

Comment: How I would apply this to simplex noise and how I would apply this to a 3D function? Also the best example given is in Python which is somewhat confusing for me.
I have an idea how to apply this to 3D Perlin but not Simplex which is constructed rather differently.

Comment: I suggest you give the concepts presented in the other answers a try and see if it works for your situation. If you still have a question after that, be a bit more specific about what you're having difficulty with here.